# Javascript regular expression split string by periods not in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression `/\.(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?=[^\.]+)/g` to split strings by periods using javascript `String.split` function, if the period is not within double quotes `""` and also if the period does not occur at the end of the string.

It seems to work well for the simple cases, like `hello ."world . works".well.` yields `['hello ', '"world . works"', 'well.']`.

But I have this complex example `'test."One .word".A short sentence." no split. " no split.".'` where it splits incorrectly to `['test."One ', 'word".A short sentence." no split', ' " no split.".']`

The expected output is `['test', '"One .word"', 'A short sentence', '" no split. " no split', '".']`

I've run out of ideas how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the expected output for the second string?

Comment: i updated the description to include it now, `['test', '"One .word"', 'A short sentence', '" no split. " no split', '".']`

Comment: Aha, so you needed to include the part outside double quotes into a single item even if there is already a quoted substring in it. The answer below covers that alright, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
/(?:"[^"]*"|[^.])+(?:\.+$)?/g
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Xm4TrU/1/).

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const regex = /(?:"[^"]*"|[^.])+(?:\.+$)?/g;
const str = `test."One .word".A short sentence." no split. " no split.".`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]                     any character except: '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.+                      '.' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

Comment: thanks works very well. I've got a question tho if you don't mind. Can I adjust the regex to not split consecutive periods? So `test ... ted."closer.by"` will become `['test ... ted', 'closer.by']`?

Comment: @mozenge Yeah, `(?:"[^"]*"|\.{2,}|[^.])+(?:\.+$)?`, [proof here](https://regex101.com/r/Xm4TrU/2).

Comment: how you make match split the text